# Method for testing whether the Web Service is alive (off or on) - Client-Side Axis

Tags: java, web-services, jakarta-ee, web-applications, axis

I need a method that returns whether a **Web Service is active or inactive**. In other words,  whether it is on or off. Does anyone know any? 
I tried to do a test (code below) to get this method on a Web Service that has password to access, user: alpha and password: 123. However, it is returning "Connection refused: connect" anyone knows the solution for this exception?

**Note:** I need for my application is a method and not a tool like SoapUI.

**Error: Connection refused: connect**

```
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
import javax.xml.rpc.ServiceException;
import org.apache.axis.client.Call;
import org.apache.axis.client.Service;

public class TestWebService {

public static void main(String... agrs) {
     String endPoint = "http://www.example.org/MyFirstWSDLFile/MyFirst";
     Service service = new Service();
     try {
       Call call = (Call) service.createCall();
       call.setUseSOAPAction(true);
       call.setSOAPActionURI("http://sap.com/xi/WebService/soap1.1");
       call.setEncodingStyle(null);
       call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.client.Call.SEND_TYPE_ATTR, Boolean.FALSE);
       call.setProperty(org.apache.axis.AxisEngine.PROP_DOMULTIREFS, Boolean.FALSE);
       call.setSOAPVersion(org.apache.axis.soap.SOAPConstants.SOAP11_CONSTANTS);
       call.setOperationName(new javax.xml.namespace.QName("http://www.example.org/MyFirstWSDLFile/", "MyFirst"));
       call.setUsername("alfa");
       call.setPassword("123");              
       call.setTargetEndpointAddress(endPoint);

       java.lang.Object _resp = call.invoke(new Object[0]);

     } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
     }
}
```

}

Comment: What happens when you connect to a service which is active and accepting connections?

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide proper exception handling.

You are getting "java.net.ConnectException" which occurs when you are trying to connect the server from the client but the server is down.

Catch this exception and and return appropriate response which indicates that the webservice is down at the moment.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification.